# Can't return ManagementObjectCollection from method

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

So I have a method which is called from ServerConnectionTools class. It should return a collection of ManagementObjects, however, if the server why we are attempting to query is not reachable, it throws a COMException.

I tried placing the Connection to the scope inside try/catch, but this then means my ret value won't be set if it fails before assignment.

What would be the best way to handle this? Up until now I've been trying to get the functionality working rather than focusing on error handling, so I'm still learning the ropes!

I also don't know if I should be raising an event within the COMException to notify the calling class that the connection failed, or handle it some other way... I would think catching a COMException in the calling class would be the wrong approach?

```
    public ManagementObjectCollection GetServicesList()
    {

        try
        {
            // Connect our scope to the actual WMI scope
            this.Scope.Connect();

            // Query system for Eclipse Services
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Caption LIKE 'xxx%'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(this.Scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection ret = searcher.Get();
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            ServerConnectionFailure?.Invoke(this, null);
        }


        return ret;
    }
```

Any thoughts are most welcome!

Cheers
Dave

Comment: If you don't want catching a COMException in the calling class, you can throw any Exception what you like in the catch(COMexception ex) block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Keep declaration of `ret` outside the `try` block, so that the
>   function it will get it's accessibility. now it belongs to the `try`
>   block only.

So your method signature will be like the following:

```
public ManagementObjectCollection GetServicesList()
    {
        ManagementObjectCollection ret=new ManagementObjectCollection(); //declaration of the collection
        try
        {
            this.Scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Caption LIKE 'xxx%'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(this.Scope, query);
            ret = searcher.Get();
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            ServerConnectionFailure?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: This is where I was going wrong... I was trying `ManagementObjectCollection ret = new ManagementObjectCollection();` but you can't instantiate it like that. It also doesn't like not assigning it a value before returning, so I just assigned null! Cheers for your help.